# React-Native-Navigation [V3], back to previous page

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Please help, i will explain first by showing the code :

home.js

```
onHelpPagePress() {
    Promise.all([
      AntDesign.getImageSource('arrowleft', 25)
    ]).then((sources) => {
      Navigation.setRoot({
        root: {
          stack: {
            children: [{
              component: {
                name: 'projectName.HelpPage',
                options: {
                  topBar: {
                    title: {
                      text: 'Screen Name 1',
                    },
                    drawBehind: false,
                    leftButtons: [
                      {
                        id: 'backButton',
                        enabled: true,
                        showAsAction: 'ifRoom',
                        component: {
                          name: 'projectName.Home',
                          passProps: {
                            color: 'white',
                            // pass event here
                          }
                        },
                        icon: sources[0],
                        color: 'white',
                      },
                    ],
                  }
                }
              },
            }]
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

it will looks like this :

```
------------------------------------
<- Screen Name 1
------------------------------------
```

how can i access the back button in the new screen? 
and could someone help me how can i go to the previous screen?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

it fixed when using navigation.showmodal